# Jquery "refuses" to update CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a class `fd-video-upload-box` that has has this element in its style:

```
background-color: rgb(236, 238, 239);
outline: 1px dashed gray !important;
```

It displays correctly.

from Javascript, as a response to a certain event, I'm trying to apply to following two changes:

```
$('.fd-video-upload-box').css({'background-color' : 'red', 'outline' : '1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important'});
```

The result is:

- The background color indeed turns to red
- The `outline` however is **completely ignored**. It doesn't even appear in the Chrome tools as an overridden element. It shows like this:

[image]

I can add it manually and it works fine:

[image]

My question is: **why isn't JQuery updating my `outline` element?**

Comment: Usually, when this happens to me, something is responding to the change after jQuery makes it.  And changing it back.

Comment: I have no other code that changes the "outline" style.

Comment: Are the top styles in an external style sheet, a script block, or an inline style attribute? If it is either of the first two, I believe the `!important` tag will break the specificity calculator of the CSS causing the inline rule not to take effect properly. If at all possible, avoid `!important` at all costs and let the _cascading_ ability of CSS do the style overrides for you...

Comment: Overall, I would never code style changes. Always use CSS and manage it in a single place. Ones you start coding styles instead of just swapping classes and another dev goes `!important` here or over there, it's just a lot of unmanageable gobble-die-gook. If you are trying to overwrite 3rd party CSS you can still do it nicely with a managed CSS file. There is tools like SCSS which can make managing CSS a lot easier and even namespace it etc.. Cascading your styles is the only way to go IMHO.

Comment: And now we see why using important is a bad practice.

Comment: Yes. It is the `!important` that screws this. however, I'm using reset.scss where outline is set to `none` with `!important` - how can I override this without using `!important` ?

Comment: I agree. I should not be coding css in my javascript and t rust the add/remove class and the "holy cascading" order.... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `css()` method ignores `!important`. From the jQuery Documentation for [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Note: .css() ignores !important declarations. So, the statement $( "p"
>   ).css( "color", "red !important" ) does not turn the color of all
>   paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes
>   instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

You can achieve setting these properties targeting `cssText` with `css()` instead:

```
$('.fd-video-upload-box').css('cssText', "background-color: red; border: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.5);");
```

Otherwise as the documentation suggests you can create a class containing these properties and use something like `addClass()` instead:

```
.foo {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
}

$('.fd-video-upload-box').addClass('foo');
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do338eyv/) demonstrating the functionality in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Thanks!

Comment: Understood. That's the source of my issues. Unfortunately in `reset.scss` which I'm using, `outline` is set to `none` with `!important` - There's no changing this without using `!important` or thinking of another solution

Comment: Thanks! the "addClass" advice was right on. I should not be coding CSS in my JS, I should just add and remove classes.